# jQuery : How to animate a span and show?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that checks mail on every 10 secods, if there is a new email, it make a bubble notification and show the total number of mail.

```
jQuery("#bubble_mate").text(responseText.totalmail);
jQuery("#bubble_mate").addClass('animating').show();
```

It animates the bubble, first time I load the page, but this function is set on an interwal, so it should animate the bubble each time there is new mail, but it Doesn't

My animation and other functions are perfect.. it is just it Doesn't animate when it is being called in set interval. it ads the number of total mail.. but no animation.

Please help me.
Regards

**Added**

This is animating class and css

```
.animating{
            -webkit-animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
            -moz-animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
            -ms-animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
            -o-animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);
            animation: animate 1s cubic-bezier(0,1,1,0);            
}

        @-webkit-keyframes animate{
            from {
                -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            }
            to {
               -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes animate{
            from {
                -moz-transform: scale(1);
            }
            to {
               -moz-transform: scale(1.7);
            }
        }

        @-ms-keyframes animate{
            from {
                -ms-transform: scale(1);
            }
            to {
               -ms-transform: scale(1.7);
            }
        }

        @-o-keyframes animate{
            from {
                -o-transform: scale(1);
            }
            to {
               -o-transform: scale(1.7);
            }
        }

        @keyframes animate{
            from {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
            to {
               transform: scale(1.7);
            }
        }
```

Comment: show at the answer: have you first HIDE the animated div?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the class once the animation is completed, and re-add it once you'll need to use it again.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#bubble_mate").addClass('animating');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#bubble_mate").removeClass('animating');        
        }, 1000); // This is the time specified in your CSS

}, 3000); // Example interval time
```

**[​JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZfDY/)**.

Comment: i resolved it myself earlier.. then saw your post just now.. anyway.. thank you .. +1 for because your answer is right.

Comment: No problem. You could mark it as "Answer" too, for future reference and when others encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery("#bubble_mate").hide().show('normal');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using keyframe animations, you may want to remove the class, then wait 1 ms and re-add the class. Adding the class multiple times will not animate it multiple times.

```
$('#test').addClass('animated');
setInterval(function(){
    $('#test').removeClass('animated');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#test').addClass('animated')
    }, 1);
}, 3000);
```

Will give the test element the class 'animated', which will start the animation, and every 3 seconds, it will remove the class, pause for 1 ms, then re-add it, which will restart the animation.

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/eV7ET/

Comment: it didnt work either.. it is randomizing the animation.. and sometimes. it just starts animating in the loop of 3 .. 5 or more..

Answer (score 0):

To show the slide down effect you have first to hide the div!

```
$("#simulate").on("click", function() { 
  console.log("mail in");
  $("#bubble_mate").text("10 new mail");
  $("#bubble_mate").addClass('animating').hide();
  $("#bubble_mate").slideDown(500);
});
```

try on this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/jQmJr/32/
​

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it myself..

in beforeSend function i added this:

```
beforeSend:function (){
jQuery("#bubble_mate").removeClass('animating');
},
```

and then on success:

```
success:function(responseText)
{
if(responseText.mails=='yes')
 {
jQuery("#bubble_mate").text(responseText.totalmail);
jQuery("#bubble_mate").addClass('animating').show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the webkitEndAnimation event to remove the animated class and the end of the animation.

Here is the live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nameIsNull/eV7ET/1/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#test').show().addClass('animated');
    }, 3000);

    $('#test').on('webkitAnimationEnd', function () { 
    $(this).removeClass('animated').hide();
    });  
});​
```

If this works for you should think of a way to get the correct event name depending on the users browser